# Sending data with axios in React (X-CSRF-Token)

Tags: http-headers, csrf, axios

I am working on form with React and axios. Previously I was using Blade template (Laravel), now everything works fine, I just wonder, if I am doing the POST request properly, because it seems like the headers are ignored.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }


    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            title: this.refs.title.value
        })

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/addpost', data, {
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content 
            }
        }).then(
            response => console.log(response.data)
        ).catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/addpost" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
                    <input ref="title" name="title" type="text" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I followed up Laravel documentation HTTP Routing, but since they made it with Ajax, I have to change the code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

Data is stored properly even when I make a post request without headers, which is probably not so good. Should I change the post request or what's the best approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just try below code for `headers` :)

```
 headers: {
             'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
             'X-CSRFToken': `Enter CSR Token here`,
          }
```

Comment: Now it throws an Error: Request failed with status code 422

Comment: I think you are doing  some syntax mistake in request data, may be you need to check JSON object

Comment: I've just added "'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'," to my old code and it seems like it's working fine.

Comment: Since you use Axios, you don't need to handle csrf token manually in every post request. Laravel already sets it up for our convenience in the file : resources/js/bootstrap.js. By default, this file contains codes that do all necessary things to handle csrf token; it automatically attaches the CSRF token to every outgoing request. Just make sure the codes are not removed or deactivated.